# SAS Studio import error

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I am trying to use SAS Studio in VirtualBox, when I run certain scripts though- I get numerous errors. Namely, when I run the following code:

```
proc import datafile = "UTDCASESTUDYDATA1.xlsx" 
            out = ti 
            dbms = excel;
run;
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: DBMS type EXCEL not valid for import.  NOTE: The SAS System
>   stopped processing this step because of errors.  NOTE: PROCEDURE
>   IMPORT used (Total process time):
>          real time           0.01 seconds
>          cpu time            0.00 seconds

I am wondering, what is the functionality of SAS Studio compared to the normal desktop version of the program? For example, when I try to run `PROC ASSOC` or certain plotting functions, I get an error that the function is "unavailable" so Im wondering if these procedures are simply limited from SAS Studio or if I have syntax errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: follow the directions on how to import data. You need to put the file in myfolders you set up at installation and import it from there. Yes there are limitations with SAS UE, not all procs available.

Comment: In this case it doesn't seem like the `proc` is unavailable, only the DBMS engine `excel` is not valid. Shouldn't it be `dbms=xlsx`? Outside from that I'm not too familiar with SAS Studio.

Comment: @user2877959 You're correct, DBMS=EXCEL is available in SAS UE, but is not valid for an XLSX file. The limitations are listed on the SAS UE website and this thread may be useful. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Analytics-U/SAS-Academics-vs-SAS-University-Edition/m-p/319732/highlight/true#M5008

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XLSX engine instead of the EXCEL engine to directly read XLSX files without having access to Microsoft products.

Sounds like you are using SAS University Edition. PROC ASSOC is not available in that because it requires a license for Enterprise Miner.

See this thread on SAS Communities 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Association-analysis-proc-assoc-and-proc-rulegen/td-p/122287